# Slick slider is stacking images on top of each other in IE11 and debugger gives error to jquery.min.js

Tags: jquery, wordpress, internet-explorer-11, slick.js

I'm having problems with IE11 in combination with Slick slider and jquery 3.5.1.
Im using the sage theme for wordpress. This is the code for the slick slider:

Jquery

```
  $(document).ready(function() {
      $('.banner__slider').slick({
          autoplay: true,
          autoplaySpeed: 4000,
          draggable: true,
          arrows: false,
          dots: false,
          fade: true,
          speed: 3000,
          infinite: true,
      });
  });
```

HTML code

```
<div class="banner banner--sub">
<div class="banner__slider">
    @foreach ($banner_images as $item)
        <div class="banner__slide">
            @php
                $format_large = 'standaard_banner_groot';
                $format_small = 'standaard_banner_klein';
            @endphp
            <picture>
                <source srcset="{{ $item['afbeelding']['sizes'][$format_small] }}" class="img-fluid" media="(max-width: 767px)">
                <img src="{{ $item['afbeelding']['sizes'][$format_large] }}" class="img-fluid"  alt="{{ $item['afbeelding']['alt'] }}">
            </picture>
        </div>
    @endforeach
</div>

@if(!is_search()  && !is_404())
    @include('components.banner-content-check')
@endif </div>
```

SCSS code

```css
.banner {
    position: relative;
    border-radius: 30px;

    iframe {
        display: table;
        border-radius: 30px;
    }

    video {
        width: 100%;
        height: auto;
        border-radius: 30px;
    }

    img {
        width: 100%;
        border-radius: 30px;
    }
}

.banner__slider {
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;

    .slick-list {
        position: relative;
        width: 100%;
    }
}

.banner__slide {
    position: relative;
    border-radius: 30px;
    float: left;

    picture {
        width: 100%;
        border-radius: 30px;
    }
}

.banner__overlay {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    background-image: radial-gradient(960px 960px at 49.97% 50%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) 0%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2) 50%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3) 100%);
    border-radius: 30px;
}

.banner__content {
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 1;
    bottom: 10%;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    color: #fff;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;

    .btn {
        @extend .btn;

        font-size: 20px;
        padding: 15px 25px;
        margin-top: 33px;
    }
}

.banner__title {
    width: 100%;
    padding: 0 10vw;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 93px;
    font-family: 'Amatic SC';
    line-height: 1;
    letter-spacing: 1.55px;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
    text-shadow: 0 0 12px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.49);
}

.banner__subtitle {
    margin-top: 10px;
    font-size: 24px;
    font-weight: 400;
    text-shadow: 0 0 12px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.29);
}

.banner__content__inner {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.banner__words {
    display: flex;
    width: 100%;
    max-width: 70%;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: space-between;
}

.banner__word {
    font-family: 'Amatic SC';
    color: #fff;
    font-size: 37px;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: space-between;

    &::after {
        content: '';
        width: 9px;
        margin-left: 2.3vw;
        display: inline-flex;
        height: 9px;
        border-radius: 50px;
        background-color: #c97962;
    }

    &:last-child {
        &::after {
            display: none;
        }
    }
}
```

The debugger in IE gives me this error:

SCRIPT445: Object doesn't support this action
File: jquery.min.js, Line: 2, Column: 31670

What am i doing wrong? Every other browser is working fine.
This is the website im talking about: [website](https://eufriedefotografie.nl)

Thanks already!!!

Comment: IE11 is no longer supported browser.

Comment: I am not able to produce the said issue with the above-mentioned sample code. I try to test the official example of slick-slider in IE 11 and it works fine. It is hard for us to check your whole site to find the cause of the issue. I suggest you try to provide an example of your slick-slider (including HTML, JS, CSS) code that can help us to reproduce the issue in IE 11. It can help us to understand the issue in a better way. Thanks for your understanding.

Comment: Ah great, thanks Deepak-MSFT. Maybe it's because i was using Virtualbox with emulated Windows 8 with IE11 :) And that's right Fresz, it's not supported anymore so i will not spend more energy in it. Thanks!

Comment: @JurgenUth, what I mean that the Jquery code that you had posted in the original post is not enough to reproduce the issue and it is hard for us to check the whole site to find the cause of the issue. So if you can provide the example of your slick-slider (including HTML, JS, CSS) code then we can try to test it and try to provide you further suggestions. Thanks for your understanding.

Comment: @Deepak-MSFT ah yes no problem. i added the extra code. Thanks!

Comment: Are you using JQmigrate on your site or maybe some other plugins are using it? I can see the message `JQMIGRATE: Migrate is installed, version 3.3.2` in the console. If possible just for testing purposes, can you please try to remove JQmigrate and make sure that the site is using the latest version of JQuery. See whether it makes any difference.